# Where can I find System.Web.Cors Documentation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Not to be confused with `System.Web.Http.Cors` . Can I use CORS from a MvcController instead? is it even possible?

I'm building a **Hybrid MVC 4** application. So Instead of using `System.Web.Http` for `ApiControllers`, I'm just using `System.Web.Mvc` and doing all the redirection myself.

So Because of that, I got NuPackage `System.AspNet.Cors` instead of its Api counterpart. As for as I've got you start by including

```
using System.Web.Cors; // Note is NOT System.Web.Http.Cors
```

So I thought of simply going to `Global.asax.cs` and add

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors().
```

Like in [This link](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API) but that **doesn't work** :(

I'm already too deep into the project to abandon the hybrid approach, so please no ApiController answers :$

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Changed the subject. Where can I find the documentation for using System.Web.Cors without WebAPI, as in System.Web.Http.ApiController

Comment: Can't find anything, did you try the EnableCors attribute?

Comment: Yes, but sadly it blows up, since it's patching an Mvc Controller instead of an ApiController =/

Comment: Might be worth asking on the MSDN forums